# NUSOAP: How to create document style wsdl using nusoap?

Tags: php, soap, wsdl, nusoap

I am using nusoap to create wsdl fle. by default it create rpc style wsdl. Is there an way to create document style wsdl using nusoap ?

Answer (score 2):

In $server->register() you have to add the following parameters:

```
$server->register(
    'MethodPublished',
    array('Req' => 'xsd:string'), // In Params
    array('Return' => 'xsd:string'), // Out Params
    'urn:WsWsdl', //  workspace name
    'urn:ErrorReportWsdl#ReportError', // soap actin
    'document', // style
    'literal', // use
    'Documentation' // Documentation
);
```

The 6th and 7th params indicate what you need

And your return of the method "MethodPublished" in this case it would have to be something similar to:

```
 return [
         "Return" => "Something"
        ];
```

Answer (score -1):

you should configure like this

```
$server->configureWSDL('servicename', 'namespace', 'endpoint', 'document');
```